# How to display 2 different values on checking & not checking checkbox in laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel-4

The code is like this:

```
{{ Form::hidden('id') }}
<td class="td-actions">
    {{ Form::checkbox('active', 'active',true) }} 
    {{ Form::hidden('active', 'inactive',false) }}
</td>
{{Form::close() }}
```

On displaying the value in web browser I get both values-active & inactive in both ckecked & unchecked cases.

How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the hidden input *before* the checkbox, and use numeric values rather than booleans:

```
{{ Form::hidden('active', '0') }}
{{ Form::checkbox('active', '1') }}
```

If the checkbox isn’t checked, then you will get a value of `0`. If the checkbox *is* checked, then you will get the checkbox’s value (`1`).